# Is there a way to general duplicate rows in excel based on multiple entries in a cell value

Tags: excel, duplicates, rows

This is my current format

[image]

I would like a formula so that the output is like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, try this short macro:

```
Sub SplitList()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, N As Long
    Dim v As String, arr, a

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1

    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, 1).Value
        arr = Split(Cells(i, 2).Value, ",")
        For Each a In arr
            Cells(j, 3).Value = v
            Cells(j, 4).Value = a
            j = j + 1
        Next a
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

The output is in cols **C** and **D**.